# Camera captured image has gone

Tags: android, android-camera

I am using the following code to call capture an image by using the camera.

```
iv2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE ); 
                 startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
                imgNo = 2;
            }
        });
```

In `onActivityResult()` I am setting the image to an ImageView by using the following code :

```
Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) imageReturnedIntent.getExtras().get("data"); 
                    Bitmap b=   getCroppedBitmap(getCroppedImage(photo));
                    iv2.setImageBitmap(b);
                    bmpimg2 = b; 
                    iv2.invalidate();
```

The image is set, but after setting the image the Activity gets refreshed and the image goes away.

How can I solve this error?
Any advice is of great help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991319/capture-image-from-camera-and-display-in-activity

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar , I have done the same thing . Please check

Comment: please comment this line Bitmap b=   getCroppedBitmap(getCroppedImage(photo));  and try

Comment: This code gives me cropped image . So I have to call this line .

Comment: This code works in my mobile . But when I try to run it in another mobile , the image has gone away .

Comment: have u check what error will come on which device because  different mobile implement different device

Comment: How can I check this ?